# How to retrieve data from database through ajax against specific id in yii2 framwork

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app

I want to send ajax object from _form.php file to retrieve data from database against object value.

The ajax url file is `regAjax.php`, but the url is not found:

> Error 404 found in console

_form.php:

```
<?= $form->field($vehicle, 'vehicleRegistrationNumber')->textInput(['maxlength' => true, 'id'=> 'regNum']) ?>
```

Ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: { regNum: regNum },
    url: "<?php echo Url::toRoute('appointments/regAjax.php')?>",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log('success');
    }
});
```

AppointmentsController:

```
public function actionRegAjax()
{
   if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
       $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
   } 
}
```

regAjax.php:

```
<?php
$regNum = $_POST['regNum'];
echo json_encode($regNum);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand that you want to retrieve data from **actionRegAjax()** function which is inside **AppointmentsController**.

Yii2 routing style works like below;

controller name and function name seperated by (/), and if any letter starts with uppercase then you have to seperate it with (-),  so all you need to do is  change URL in your ajax to

```
url: "appointments/reg-ajax",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    cache: false,
    data: { regNum: regNum },
    url: "<?= Url::to(['appointments/reg-ajax'])?>",
    success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Your access to controller Action was not appropriate. Find the above appropriate method to do so.